# Pandas convert multiple rows as header (multi level)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert 3 rows as multi level column header in pandas dataframe.

Sample dataframe is,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['foo_0', 'bar_0', 1, 2, 3], 'b':['foo_0', 'bar_0', 11, 12, 13],
'c':['foo_1', 'bar_1', 21, 22, 23], 'd':['foo_1', 'bar_1', 31, 32, 33]})
```

expected output looks like, wherein yellow colored is a column multi level column header.

[image]

Thank you, 
-Nilesh

Comment: Please always add what you are trying to archieve, the expected output **and the actual output**.

Comment: @JakobF I have added expected output. I didn't understood "actual output"?

Comment: The combining of levels does not happen like that.  The Q&D way to do it is `df.T.set_index([0, 1], append=True).T` and you'll see that it isn't exactly as you expect.

Comment: What’s the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it a substitute for guides, tutorials, and documentation.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you, yes exactly this is what i was looking for.